# How can I open the Firefox Add-ons Manager page from a link?

Tags: firefox, hyperlink, permissions, firefox-addon, href

I know that If I try in the browser: about:addons it will take me to the addons page in order to set a permission
BUT I need to have in my page a buton that does this.
I tried like this:

```
<a href="about:addons">addons page</a>
```

But it doesn't do anything.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Interesting, putting this in the HTML doesn't work? What is the context? A page of your addon? Or website?

Comment: Website, and it's for security reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/The_about_protocol

Note: You must access about: protocol pages by typing them into the address bar. Attempts to navigate through window.location will throw —  Error: Access to 'about:addons' from script denied.